# Move all files within folders beginning with string

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
find . -type d -name "2016*" -exec mv {}/* ../../../Pictures/2016/ \;
```

To move all files in any folder beginning with 2016 to another folder called Pictures/2016. It is giving no file/directory found however echoing gives this:

```
mv ./2016-02-13/* ../../../Pictures/2016/
```

Any ideas clever people of Stack Exchange?

Comment: Two things to try: (1) Quote the `{}/*` (so it's `mv '{}/*' ../../.....`), and (2) Add `-v` to `mv`, or even instead of `-exec mv` do `-exec echo mv` to see what would be executed.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Quoting won't work, as the glob will then never be expanded.

Comment: Share what the find returns, without the -exec {}

Comment: Also concider using xargs...  `| xargs -0 -I {} mv {} /destdir/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using subshells with `find`

The `*` will be expanded by your shell before `find` sees it, so that's wrong – it might even cause data loss. You can't quote it, because then it will not be expanded at all.

What you need is a subshell that receives the folder as an argument, then does the expansion later:

```
find . -type d -name '2016*' -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0"/* /path/to/target/' {} \;
```

The `--` prevents files with a starting `-` from being interpreted as `mv` options, and you should quote the folder name in `"$0"`.

#### Using pure Bash

Alternative use of recursive globbing with Bash ≥ 4.0:

```
shopt -s globstar
mv **/2016*/* /path/to/target/
```

I guess this is much cleaner, although it breaks with a too large number of files.